# Remove everything after first whitespace in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes with some values inside the hashes containing spaces. I would like to run through every array element and every value within the hashes to remove any spaces and the following characters past the space. An example of my data would be

```
arrayHash = [{:firstname=>'Anne Marie', :lastname=>'Hook', :email=>'test@test.com', :id=>1}, 
           {:firstname=>'Michael', :lastname=>'Rodriguez', :email=>'test2@test.com', :id=>2}]
```

So for example on the firstname key, I would like to take 'Anne Marie' and reduce it to just 'Anne', and do the same for every element in this array.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. We'd like to know what you tried. It's better for us to correct your code, than to write code for you, which isn't what SO is for. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" is a good read also.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? More may be coming, you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arrayHash.map! do |hash|
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
    h[k] = v.is_a?(String) ? v.split(' ').first : v
  end
end
#=>[{:firstname=>"Anne", :lastname=>"Hook", :email=>"test@test.com", :id=>1}, {:firstname=>"Michael", :lastname=>"Rodriguez", :email=>"test2@test.com", :id=>2}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because this is an array of hash rather than a straight hash. This doesn't access the hash within the array element.

Comment: @coyote_rey I do not understand your comment. Run the code and see, that it returns what you described in the OP

Comment: I've ran this code and I'm not seeing it affecting the firstname value. I see it saying just Anne in the output of that line, but displaying arrayHash[0] after the fact, I am still seeing 'Anne Marie'

Comment: @coyote_rey you did not say you wanted to modify the original hashes.Let me update the answer

Comment: @coyote_rey check it now (notice the bang in `map!`)

Comment: Ah thank you. Yeah sorry about the poor wording. That fixes it for me.

Comment: If you're testing that it's a String, then `to_s` is redundant. You already know it's a string.

Comment: @tadman correct, `to_s` is left after my initial attempt. will edit, thanks for noticing!

Comment: It's a tidy solution, just observing how it could be even more concise.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to mutate `arrayHash`, you could do the following:

```
arrayHash.each { |h| h.each { |k,v| h[k] = v.is_a?(String) ? v[/\A\S*/] : v } }
  #=> [{:firstname=>"Anne", :lastname=>"Hook", :email=>"test@test.com", :id=>1},
  #    {:firstname=>"Michael", :lastname=>"Rodriguez", :email=>"test2@test.com", :id=>2}]
```

`arrayHash` is mutated:

```
arrayHash
  #=> [{:firstname=>"Anne", :lastname=>"Hook", :email=>"test@test.com", :id=>1},
  #    {:firstname=>"Michael", :lastname=>"Rodriguez", :email=>"test2@test.com", :id=>2}]
```

The regex `/\A\S*/` matches the beginning of the string followed by zero or more characters other than whitespace. For the string `v`, `v[/\A\S*/]` returns the match. (See the method [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)).

If you do not wish to mutate `arrayHash`, this is one way:

```
arrayHash.map { |h| h.merge(h) { |_,v,_| v.is_a?(String) ? v[/\A\S*/] : v } }
  #=> [{:firstname=>"Anne", :lastname=>"Hook", :email=>"test@test.com", :id=>1},
  #    {:firstname=>"Michael", :lastname=>"Rodriguez", :email=>"test2@test.com", :id=>2}]
```

`arrayHash` is unchanged:

```
arrayHash
  #=> [{:firstname=>"Anne Marie", :lastname=>"Hook", :email=>"test@test.com", :id=>1},
  #    {:firstname=>"Michael", :lastname=>"Rodriguez", :email=>"test2@test.com", :id=>2}]
```

In the second case I've used the form of the method [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) which employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all the keys. See the doc for an explanation of the values of the three block variables (the first and third of which I've represented with an underscore to signify that they are not used in the block calculation).